# Default view in look up record in Set Regarding in Outlook CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to default **Look in** to 'ALLorders ' view when 'orders' is selected in **Look for**. This is located in the pop up when “set regarding” is hit in OUTLOOK and choose Order in the drop down on the email to attach the order.

Is it possible to default LOOK in to All Orders instead of Order Lookup View?

[Look up record view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkXAe.png)

Thanks,
Shruthi Rajoli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were in the web client, you'd have an unsupported option.  From Outlook you have no good options, unfortunately.

If you're on premise and the business doesn't want to let go of the requirement, you might be able to do something really hacky: modify the dialog's aspx page with some JavaScript that would automatically flip the look for dropdown.  But this approach has a lot of problems: 1) unsupported 2) your changes might get lost if you install an update 3) it might not be possible to determine via JS if the button was clicked from Outlook vs web.